# How to create a page with dynamic controls in asp.net? How can I define a control collection?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-plugins

In my ASP.NET web application project I want to create a page with dynamic controls.
Please see the details.
I have a a Page named AddNotificationParameters.aspx.
While passing a querystring parameter to this page it needs to load controls based on the querystring.
The controls will be different based on the querystring parameter.
What is the best approach to handle these types of scenario.
Pls advice

Comment: If the querystring value is checkreturn I want to load 2 textbox controls. Also if the querystring value is balanceDue then I want to load 2 checkbox and a taxtbox control.The working is in this way. Please advice

Answer (score 3):

Use a gridview or repeater and bind the data to it. Then you can generate dynamic controls using it. This is just a vague idea. Please post more details for getting an exact idea.